# For my algorithm, is there some function that will tell me exactly when my list of 3-sets will probably have an exact-cover?

Tags: combinatorics, np-complete

Algorithm.

- Write down a set of integers and call it Universe $X$.  Make sure
  the quantity of elements is always divisible by $3$.
- Create a list, by writing down 3-sets by random with no intentions of
  creating an exact cover of $X$.

An exact cover is a combination of $k$ $3sets$ that "cover" each element in $X$ without overlap. $k$ is always the length of $X$ divided by $3$.

Rules for the algorithm.

1. Do not write down 3-sets more than once. (Edit: 3-sets may be selected more than once, but duplicates must be removed in the list.)
2. Only create 3-sets that have elements in $X$
3. Sets are ordered from smallest to largest values.
4. Do not stop, use as a while loop. (Edit: Keep writing down random 3-sets.)

### Question

Using the manual algorithm above for all universes of $X$, is there some function that will tell me exactly when my list of 3-sets will probably have an exact-cover?

Say $|X|$ = $3k$, how many random 3-sets do I need in the list to have > 60% probability that there is an exact cover?

**Examples**

Given $X$ with 3-elements, a list of 3-sets would only require one random guess.

$X$ = 1,2,3

Exact Cover {1,2,3}

As $X$ gets larger it takes more random guesses for a combination of $k$ sets to form an exact cover.

$X$ = 1,2,3,4,5,6

{1,2,5},{3,5,6},{1,3,4},{1,2,4}

Exact Cover {1,2,4},{3,5,6}

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/124963/discussion-on-question-by-travis-wells-for-my-algorithm-is-there-some-function).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $|X|=6$ there are $20\ 3-$sets.  You are looking to get one of these sets and its complement.  If you have chosen $k$ sets so far and not found an exact-cover, there are $k$ of the ones that are left that will give you one and $20-2k$ that will not, so the chance you will get one is $\frac k{20-k}$.  After two draws you have about $0.0526$ of having a cover, after three $0.1579$, after four $0.3065$, after five $0.4799$ and after six $0.6533$.  It gets harder for larger $|X|$ because there is not an easy way to say which sets you are looking for.  I think I would just write a simulation and see how it comes out.

Here is an approach for larger $k$.  There are ${3k \choose 3}\ 3-$sets.  There are ${{3k \choose 3} \choose k}\ k-$sets of $3-$sets. There are $\frac {(3k)!}{3!^kk!}$ exact-covers.  We make the assumption that when you add a $3-$set to the list each $k-$set of $3-$sets has an equal in independent probability to be an exact-cover.  I don't know how to justify this, but it should not be too far wrong.  We can then compute how many $3-$sets we need to have a good chance of an exact cover based on the number of $k-$sets.  The chance a $k-$set is an exact cover is $\frac {\frac {(3k)!}{3!^kk!}}{{{3k \choose 3} \choose k}}$.  If we have chosen $m\ 3-$sets we have ${m \choose k}\ k-$sets of $3-$ sets.  We should have an exact cover about when
$${m \choose k}=\frac {{{3k \choose 3} \choose k}}{\frac {(3k)!}{3!^kk!}}$$
This gives
$$\begin {array} {r r r r r} k&\text{numerator}&\text{denominator}&{m \choose k}&m \\
3&95284&280&340.3&14\\
4&94966795&15400&6167&21\\
5&1.589\cdot10^{11}&1401400&113432&29
\end {array}$$

Comment: On **shaky ground**, I question whether [Linearity of Expectation](https://brilliant.org/wiki/linearity-of-expectation/) can be applied here.  In one of my comments, where $n=6$ and $r ~$ 3-sets are randomly chosen (**with replacement**) from the $20$ possible 3-sets, I set $Q = [1 - (1/2)^r]$, which equals the probability that any element in $\{1,2,\cdots,6\}$ is included in the $r ~$ 3-sets.  **My question is**, does this imply that the chance of  an exact cover is $Q^6 = [1 - (1/2)^r]^6$?

Comment: I was following the post in choosing without replacement, as it threw away duplicates.

Comment: @RossMillikan Yes, duplicates aren't allowed. Only one 3-set of its kind is allowed.

Comment: @user2661923:  I am not using linearity of expectation.  I computed the chance of finding an exact cover by $k$ draws from the expression I showed.

Comment: Yes, I realize that.  I am asking whether Linearity of Expectation can be used as a shortcut.  If so, it easily solves the problem for general $n$.  For example, with $n$ a multiple of $3$, and $r~$ 3-sets chosen, then the chance of a single 3-set **not** containing (random) $(i)$ is $p = [(n-3)/n].$  This implies that the chance that $r ~$ 3-sets **do** contain $(i)$ is $Q = [1 - p^r]$.  The question is **whether** the chance of an exact cover is therefore $Q^n$?

Comment: @user2661923:  It is a reasonable approach, but I think it will be too hard for larger $|X|$.  You would want to calculate the chance that for one subset it is in an exact-covering set.  That means being a part of a group of covering disjoint subsets.  I don't see how to calculate that, but maybe somebody else does.

Comment: Does your last comment signify that you do **not** think that  Linearity of Expectation can be directly applied?  If that is incorrect and you do think that it can be directly applied, then, letting $f(n,r)$ denote the chance of an exact cover, given $n$ numbers and $r ~$ 3-sets, would not the closed form of $f(n,r)$ be $$\left[ ~1 - \left(\frac{n-3}{n}\right)^r ~\right]^n?$$  If you agree, then, for any $n$ (e.g. $n=100$), can't logarithms with a handheld calculator immediately identify (for example) the smallest $r$ such that $f(n,r) > 0.60$?

Comment: @user2661923:  It is important to distinguish between the chance of a cover and the expectation of some cover being present.  The expectation is the number of covers expected.  It counts cases with two covers twice, three covers three times, etc.  If the chance of a cover is small, so the chance of two is small$^2$, this works well.  If you are in the regime where covers are reasonably likely you need to consider the effect of multiple covers on the calculation.  It can make a difference between the number of draws to get an expected number of covers of 0.5 and the number of draws to get 1.

Comment: @user2661923:  so my answer is that linearity cannot be easily applied.

Comment: **That** is the response that I was looking for.  You just stretched my intuition.  This means that Linearity of Expectation **is** appropriate for computing the **expected** number of elements in $\{1,2,\cdots, n\}$ which will be *covered* by $r ~$ 3-sets but **is not** appropriate for (in this problem) computing the probability of an exact cover, given $r ~$ 3-sets.  Have I understood you correctly?

Comment: Yes, you have, but you are calculating the expected number of exact covers.  A parallel is flipping a biased coin with the chance of heads $0.01\ 50$ times.  The expected number of heads if $\frac 12$ by linearity.  The chance of at least one head is $1-.01^{99} \approx 0.4$  The difference comes because the expected number calculation counts those strings with two heads twice, while the one of at least one head counts them once

Comment: I'll have to wait till my work is done, I can easily confuse myself because of how hard I think. I'll be back.